# .Net Core IsAuthenticated false even if I use manually HttpContext.SignInAsync

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, jwt

I have my app using both cookie and bearer authentication:

```
var membershipService = configuration.GetValue<string>("MembershipService:BaseUri");
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie()
    .AddJwtBearer(opt =>
    {
        opt.Audience = "gateway";
        opt.Authority = membershipService;
        opt.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        opt.SaveToken = true;
        opt.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
        {
            OnTokenValidated = (context) =>
            {
                var accessToken = context.SecurityToken as JwtSecurityToken;
                if (accessToken != null)
                {
                    ClaimsIdentity identity = context.Principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
                    if (identity != null)
                    {
                        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("access_token", accessToken.RawData));
                    }
                }
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };
});
```

Everything works fine when I send `access_token` in headers.

But if I send without token in header on second request (first one with authorization header), it seems that `User` doesn't know anything about the previous authentication. Even if I do `HttpContext.SignInAsync("Cookies", User)`, the next request, e.g. after pressing F5, doesn't have the user authenticated.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, no cookie will be created unless you actually call `SignInAsync` on the cookie scheme. So you will need to do that. But just because a cookie is being sent by the user that does not mean that the cookie scheme will run and attempt to authenticate the user.

You call `AddAuthentication` like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
```

This means that the JWT Bearer authentication will be the default authentication scheme. So when the authentication middleware runs, it will attempt to authenticate *that* authentication scheme, and only that. If you have multiple authentication schemes, then only the default authentication scheme will actually attempt to authenticate the user. Otherwise there would be a conflict if multiple schemes could authenticate the user.

So in your case, the user is not being authenticated because the cookie authentication scheme is simply not running. You should think about what your default scheme should be. If you want to use the bearer token only as a “sign-in”, then it makes sense to use the cookie authentication scheme as the default. You could then instead provide a login action that required the bearer scheme and then signed in the cookie scheme:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes=JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login()
{
    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, User);
    return View();
}
```

You could then invoke that route with your `access_token` and have the `Authorize` attribute trigger an authentication on the JWT Bearer scheme, and use the user to sign in with the cookie scheme. So subsequent requests would use the cookie scheme (as the default) and the user would be recognized.

Finally note that JWT Bearer authentication is *usually* considered as a stateless authentication method and sending the token explicitly on *every request* is considered the correct practice. So generating a cookie out of it would be a bit odd.

Comment: a brilliant solution !

Comment: really crystal clear explanation, thank you. Actually I have SPA and I need cookies auth scheme only for page refreshing because I have some initial user data being pulled with first request if user signed in.

Comment: not working with CORE 5 as  httpcontext does not carry Signin method

Comment: @namvo You will need to have a using for the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication` namespace in order for [those extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticationhttpcontextextensions?view=aspnetcore-5.0) to be available.